# PROJECT_ID in GCM Message is null

Tags: android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, android-intentservice

**Background**

- I have one Android App
- I have two google API  projects , so obviously two SENDER_ID and two API Keys and both these projects are enabled for Google Cloud Messaging.
- One broadcast receiver which extracts the EXTRAS from the intent and spawns different IntentService for each Project based on "from" key in the intent extras bundle. Also the IntentService is spawned using ComponentName.

This "from" key is the PROJECT_ID/ SENDER_ID , and based on these I spawn a different Intent Service to handle the intent.

Steps to do this have been learnt from here : https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

**Issue**
When the application launches, I call two JAVA classes which register to GCM server using the GoogleCoudMessaging singleton with respective PROJECT_ID/SENDER_ID.

This is implemented successfully and I get registration ID for both.

But when I fire a push notification for both these google projects, I receive intent extras for both of them and one has PROJECT_ID under the key "from"  and the other one has null under this key.

The problem is whichever project registered second always gets the PROJECT_ID back in the push message, whereas the project that registers first does not get the PROJECT_ID back int he intent extras.

Is there something obvious that I am missing in implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you register only once to GCM, using both sender IDs :

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(contexts);
gcm.register (sender1,sender2);
```

This way you'll have a single registration ID that works for both senders.

Hopefully that will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I unfortunately have a requirement that makes it a mandate to register both separately.The "from" key, does Google server put in that value? Or is their a different origin for that?

Comment: @Sudhanshu Yes, I believe the GCM server puts the value there.

Comment: Ahh then I guess I can't manipulate the Third party webservers to add that field.. Is there any other way this distinction or value for "From" key can be achieved? Like a different design that could help ?

Comment: @Sudhanshu You could add a custom key in your payload (inside `data`) with a value that would identify the sender, but that would allow one sender to impersonate the other sender by using its ID.

Comment: Yes this is a risky alternative. But thanks for suggesting. I am going to keep this question open for a while to see if anybody else found themselves in this predicament and if they were able to solve it. Thanks !